# Remove the @{} tag from object output PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need help removing the @{} extensions from object output.

The code bellow is listing the last modified file inside a folder. But the output is inside extension @{}.

I have tried the Out-String but it is not working.

```
function scriptA() {
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Select fullname -last 1
}

function scriptB() {
Get-ChildItem $path2 | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Select fullname -last 1
}

$data1=ScritA
$data2=ScriptB

$result=@()
$list=@{
FirstFile=$data1
SecondFile=$data2
}

$result+= New-Object psobject -Property $list
$result | Export-Csv -append -Path  $csv
```

This will output: 
**FirstFile** @{data1} and **SecondFile** @{data2}

Comment: `Select fullname` -> `Select -Expand fullname`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell how to remove \`{}@\` from output. Is there a special command to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265234/powershell-how-to-remove-from-output-is-there-a-special-command-to-do-it) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/28419567/478656 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46184120/478656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your functions slightly to this -

```
function scriptA() {
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname -last 1
}

function scriptB() {
Get-ChildItem $path2 | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname -last 1
}
```

Doing that will let you select only the `FullName` property.

**OR**

If you do not want to change the functions, change the `$list` assignment to -

```
$list=@{
FirstFile = $data1.FullName
SecondFile = $data2.FullName
}
```

Comment: Calling the object with the attribute, fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: $list=@{
FirstFile = $data1.FullName
SecondFile = $data2.FullName
}

Answer (score 0):

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{FirstFile = ($a = (Get-ChildItem $path1),(Get-ChildItem $path2) |
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {$_[-1].FullName})[0];SecondFile = $a[1]} |
Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation
```